# How to use default parameters for jenkins build when triggered from TFS Queue Jenkins Job task?

Tags: jenkins, queue, jobs

I am triggering a jenkins build via TFS Build's "Queue Jenkins Job" task. I am able to trigger the the job, but job fails because it's not reading default values of the job parameters.
I have been reading but all I could find are ways to send parameters or overwride all params with a blank.
I have already enabled parameterized job in the tfs task.
I was wondering if there is a way to tell jenkins to use default parameter values defined in job already.

Thanks

Comment: Post code for us to help u

Comment: Thanks for comment. It's not from code, I'm triggering jenkins build through vnext build task in tfs.